# R - Removing only one part of the empty rows of a zoo objects

Tags: r

I have merged several time series together and I need to subset the data so that the first row has no NAs. Below the first row there can be NAs, even in the entire row. I will have to take care of them through interpolation.
Here is a simplified data example:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(NA, NA, 3, 2, 6, NA, 5), y = c(NA, NA, 24, 11, NA, NA, 8), z=c(NA, NA, NA, 33, 22, NA, 19))
date <- c("2001-03-30", "2001-03-31", "2001-04-01", "2001-04-02", "2001-04-03", "2001-04-04", "2001-04-05")
DFz <- zoo(DF, order.by = date)
DFz
x  y  z
2001-03-30 NA NA NA
2001-03-31 NA NA NA
2001-04-01  3 24 NA
2001-04-02  2 11 33
2001-04-03  6 NA 22
2001-04-04 NA NA NA
2001-04-05  5  8 19
```

What I'd like to obtain is a new zoo matrix starting from the first row having no NAs, (i.e. from the fourth row in the example above), eventual NA rows below the first row must stay instead. I'd like to obtain this:

```
2001-04-02  2 11 33
2001-04-03  6 NA 22
2001-04-04 NA NA NA
2001-04-05  5  8 19
```

I have tried different ways, but I don't really know how to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: na.trim.ts(DFz)

Comment: Thanks @Henk! Actually na.trim.ts(DFz) gives me a warning message, but following your suggestion I have found and tried a simple na.trim(DFz) which works perfectly!

Comment: Do note that if the last rows have also NAs they will get trimmed by the `na.trim` function.

Comment: @PierreChevallier Indeed I was just commenting about it. Is there a way to keep the last rows and trim only the first ones?

Comment: Use the `sides = "left"` argument.
EDIT: Woops somebody was faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try `na.trim` which will dispatch the `na.trim.zoo` method:

```
na.trim(DFz, sides = "left")
```

giving:

```
            x  y  z
2001-04-02  2 11 33
2001-04-03  6 NA 22
2001-04-04 NA NA NA
2001-04-05  5  8 19
```

By default `na.trim` trims from both sides so we use `sides` to ensure that trailing NAs are kept.

**Note:** You may wish to familiarize yourself with the various `na.*` zoo methods.  They should be listed among the output of this command:

```
apropos("^na[.]")
```

Comment: Thanks! I use several na.* but didn't think to use apropos and search for an na.* that I didn't know.